# JQuery menu MOD

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering if I could get some help with some coding. I have this code here which works great but I would really like to make it to where the first UL is activated as default. I'm at a loss for where and how to add this. Any advice is much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        }
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }
        if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's preventing you from using [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)?  Also, it helps readability if you indent your code.

Comment: Define activated - do you mean clicked or is given the class active?

Comment: Just add `active` to your `class=""` in the HTML for whichever `<ul>` you want active on pageload.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Honestly I know absolutely nothing about JQuery but I have seen the `.eq(0)` before but wasnt sure how to use it. Also sorry about the pasted code, it's my first post and I was getting frustrated trying to figure out how to use the code tag.

Comment: Oh yea and by activated I just want the first option to be displayed. I couldnt imagine there would be much of a difference between being clicked and having the activated class.

Thanks Deryck I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen people do this by writing the same code twice. To perform the procedure, trigger the action it's bound to after binding it. In this instance you want to only trigger it on the first element, so filter first.

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    // blah blah
}).first().trigger('click'); // you can use }).first().click() if you prefer
```

Comment: AH HAH! It worked, thanks so much! However the nerd in me is still trying to make sense of the other two options. `.eq(0)` (tried putting this part of code all over the script) and also adding active to the class.